# Interrupt Sleep method of TThread (and only Sleep method)

Tags: multithreading, delphi

I am looking for an ability to interrupt `TThread` quickly.

Some suggest to interrupt it with `TerminateThread`, but I do not want this violence.

I implemented an exit check in `Execute` method, but there is one thing I cannot influence: an ongoing `Sleep`. When a thread is in `Sleep` the only thing left to me is to wait until `Sleep` finishes.

I made a following workaround:

```
procedure TMyThreadTimer._smartSleep(Timeout: Integer);
var
  repeats: Integer;
begin
  repeats := (Timeout div 50) + 1;
  while (not Terminated) and (repeats > 0) do begin
    Sleep(50);
    Dec(repeats);
  end;
end;
```

but it looks not good.

Is there an ability to interrupt `Sleep`, but not the thread?

Comment: Do not sleep, wait for an interruptible event, like `TEvent`. Specify a timeout. If you want to "cancel" this waiting operation, signal the event so the waiting is over.

Comment: In any case, your `while` / `Dec` loop makes no sense - why not just use a simple `for` loop?

Comment: I reverted your edit. Please don't ask new questions in edits, especially not new questions that are off topic here.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use a `TEvent` object instead of `Sleep()`, eg:

```
type
  TMyThreadTimer = class(TThread)
  private
    FTermEvent: TEvent;
    procedure _smartSleep(Timeout: Integer);
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
    procedure TerminatedSet; override; // XE2+ only *
  public
    constructor Create(ACreateSuspended: Boolean); override;
    destructor Destroy; override;
  end;

constructor TMyThreadTimer.Create(ACreateSuspended: Boolean);
begin
  inherited Create(ACreateSuspended);
  FTermEvent := TEvent.Create(nil, True, False, '');
end;

destructor TMyThreadTimer.Destroy;
begin
  //inherited calls TerminatedSet where FTermEvent should not be freed yet
  inherited;
  FTermEvent.Free;
end;

procedure TMyThreadTimer.Execute;
begin
  ...
end;

procedure TMyThreadTimer.TerminatedSet;
begin
  FTermEvent.SetEvent;
end;

procedure TMyThreadTimer._smartSleep(Timeout: Integer);
begin
  FTermEvent.WaitFor(Timeout);
end;
```

This way, while the thread is running normally, `_smartSleep()` will sleep more efficiently, and as soon as you `Terminate()` the thread (as `Terminate()` calls `TerminatedSet()`), any sleep that is in progress will stop immediately.

<sup>*</sup> If you are using a Delphi version prior to XE2, you will have to implement your own method to signal the `TEvent` when needed.  For example, adding a public `Stop()` method to the thread class and have it call `Terminate()` and `FTermEvent.SetEvent()`, then call that method instead of calling `Terminate()` directly.

Comment: Thank you. You are calling `inherited Create(ACreateSuspended);`, but I got problems when destroying a suspended thread. Destructor got stuck at `inherited`, so I decided never to allow suspended threads.

Comment: @Paul Presumably an initially-suspended thread would be started at some point. Why even create a thread just to destroy it before it does anything? Furthermore, the point of creating a thread in a suspended state is that you might need to do some additional work ***before*** it's ready to start running. If you start a thread before it's _ready_ You most ***certainly can expect*** peculiar, erratic, hard to fix bugs. Imposing a _poorly justified_ hard-nosed rule on client code just hampers the possibility of writing the client code correctly.

Comment: The `TThread` destructor resumes a suspended thread and waits for it to terminate. But since `FTermEvent` is freed before the base destructor is called, bad things will happen when the thread is resumed. NEVER try to destroy a thread that has never started running, or is actively running. Always explicitly resume and terminate a thread before destroying it.

Comment: Isn't the right way to deal with that to ensure that the terminate event is destroyed later?